# What methods are called when I drag within a QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt

I would like to be able to drag instances of QGraphicsItem around in a QGraphicsScene and invoke custom code when the user stops dragging.

I can make the graphics items draggable with the following complete working example (using PyQt. C++ users just read `self` as `this`)

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindowUi(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.scene = Scene(0, 0, 300, 300, self)
        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.addItem(Square(0,0,50,50))

class Scene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print("Scene got mouse press event")
        print("Event came to us accepted: %s"%(e.isAccepted(),))
        QtGui.QGraphicsScene.mousePressEvent(self, e)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        print("Scene got mouse release event")
        print("Event came to us accepted: %s"%(e.isAccepted(),))
        QtGui.QGraphicsScene.mouseReleaseEvent(self, e)

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        print('Scene got drag move event')

class Square(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        print("Square got mouse press event")
        print("Event came to us accepted: %s"%(e.isAccepted(),))
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.mousePressEvent(self, e)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        print("Square got mouse release event")
        print("Event came to us accepted: %s"%(e.isAccepted(),))
        QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.mouseReleaseEvent(self, e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindowUi()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When we click on the square we see the print statements from both the Scene and the Square. The square can be dragged. When we release the mouse we see the print statements from both the Scene and the Square.

The question is: **what methods are executing during and on completion of the drag?** For instance, what needs to be added to the example to print the position of the square when I release the mouse?

Comment: `QGraphicsItem` has a [pos()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsitem.html#pos) function which returns its position. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: That's definitely part of it. I want to have a method called when the user finished moving a QGraphicsRectItem. I'm starting to think that I should store an "itemBeingMoved" variable when the user clicks and then override mouseReleasedEvent such that it checks if there's an itemBeingMoved, and if so does useful logic. Does this make sense? Is some of this already done for me?

Comment: That's one way to do it. Or you can store the position of your item in `mousePressEvent` and check if it has changed in `mouseReleaseEvent`.

Comment: Indeed. I'd still have to store a reference to the item that's being moved, would I not? Also, I think what has been confusing me so far is that moving a QGraphicsItem around in a QGraphicsScene is _not_ "drag and drop". This has been causing my searches to fail. Now that I know this I'm starting to get a clearer picture.

Comment: You won't have to store a reference to the item that is being moved if you do the position checks inside the item's `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` instead of scene's `mousePressEvent`/`mouseReleaseEvent`.

Comment: Great advice, thanks. Now I have to ask another question. I edit the example program to print out True/False if the incoming mouse press or release events are already accepted when they get to my custom handlers. When I click on the square I find that the mousePressEvent is not accepted when it gets to the scene, but is accepted when it gets to the square. Ok, so the scene accepts it. But when I release I see that the scene does not accept it. What's going on?

Comment: You should probably create a new question for that.